# Replacing an output from an SQL statement with a different string

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, case

I currently have an output that is populating a table. One of the outputs it gives is a year from the student's table. Whenever 6 is outputted as the year I need it to return L6 and when 7 is outputted I need U6. I have made an attempt bellow:

```
"$stmt = $conn->prepare(
              "SELECT st.Name AS student, st.House AS house, T1.Name AS T1, T2.Name AS T2, T3.Name AS T3
              CASE
                WHEN st.Year = 6 THEN 'L6'
                WHEN st.Year = 7 THEN 'U6'
                ELSE st.Year
              END CASE as year
              From Students AS st INNER JOIN Student_Choices AS sc
              ON st.Username = sc.Username INNER JOIN Current_DB AS db
              ON sc.DB_year = db.DB
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c1
              ON sc.T1_Choice = c1.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T1
              ON c1.Sport_ID = T1.Sport_ID
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c2
              ON sc.T2_Choice = c2.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T2
              ON c2.Sport_ID = T2.Sport_ID
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c3
              ON sc.T3_Choice = c3.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T3
              ON c3.Sport_ID = T3.Sport_ID
              ");
```

I then get an error:

> errorSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN st.Year = 6 THEN 'L6' WHEN st.' at line 2

Any solutions would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is as follows:

```
SELECT st.Name AS student, st.House AS house,
              (CASE WHEN st.Year = 6 THEN 'L6' WHEN st.Year = 7 THEN 'U6' ELSE st.Year END) as year,
              T1.Name AS T1, T2.Name AS T2, T3.Name AS T3
              From Students AS st
              INNER JOIN Student_Choices AS sc
              ON st.Username = sc.Username INNER JOIN Current_DB AS db
              ON sc.DB_year = db.DB
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c1
              ON sc.T1_Choice = c1.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T1
              ON c1.Sport_ID = T1.Sport_ID
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c2
              ON sc.T2_Choice = c2.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T2
              ON c2.Sport_ID = T2.Sport_ID
              INNER JOIN Choices AS c3
              ON sc.T3_Choice = c3.Choice_ID
              INNER JOIN Sports AS T3
              ON c3.Sport_ID = T3.Sport_ID
```

CASE needed to be in brackets and the as year needed to be after when being selected

Answer (score 0):

The case statements cannot sit on their own like that, they have to be part of the main query. Remove them and instead try

```
SELECT 
  st.Name AS student, 
  st.House AS house, 
  CASE 
    WHEN st.Year = 6 THEN 'L6' 
    WHEN st.Year = 7 THEN 'U6'
    ELSE st.Year 
  END CASE as year
```

...etc

Comment: Still not working, I've updated the question @ADyson

Comment: you missed a comma after T3 I think. You need a comma between each field.

Comment: Nope it wasn't that @ADyson